# Dropout between two Conv layers and Batchnormalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, dropout

```
model3=models.Sequential()
model3.add(Conv2D(32, 
(3,3),padding='same',kernel_regularizer=reg,input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model3.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model3.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model3.add(Dropout(0.2))
model3.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_regularizer=reg))
model3.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model3.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model3.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

I am interested to know how dropout works between two conv layers. If dimensions of feature maps in layer `L` are `(m, n_h, n_w, n_c)` and a filter of size `(f, f, n_c)` is convolve on it, do we randomly shut down some units across the `n_c` channels in the layer `L` before performing convolution? Dropout on a MaxPool layer is straightforward though.

**BatchNorm**

```
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 32)        128       
________________________________________________________________
```

The third column is the number of parameters of the layer. For batchnorm layer, do we normalize each feature map across the batch so that for each feature map we will have 4 parameters and thus in my case, I have `32*4 = 128` parameters? If I am wrong, can someone correct me. I assume my assumption is wrong, as I read somewhere that we normalize across the channel. But this doesn't tally the number of parameters of the layers.

Answer (score 1):

For the `BatchNormalization` layer, if you read its doc/[source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L16) carefully, its number of parameters is dependent on the following four parameters:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    dim = input_shape[self.axis]
    if dim is None:
        raise ValueError('Axis ' + str(self.axis) + ' of '
                         'input tensor should have a defined dimension '
                         'but the layer received an input with shape ' +
                         str(input_shape) + '.')
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=len(input_shape),
                                axes={self.axis: dim})
    shape = (dim,)

    if self.scale:
        self.gamma = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                     name='gamma',
                                     initializer=self.gamma_initializer,
                                     regularizer=self.gamma_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.gamma_constraint)
    else:
        self.gamma = None
    if self.center:
        self.beta = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                    name='beta',
                                    initializer=self.beta_initializer,
                                    regularizer=self.beta_regularizer,
                                    constraint=self.beta_constraint)
    else:
        self.beta = None
    self.moving_mean = self.add_weight(
        shape=shape,
        name='moving_mean',
        initializer=self.moving_mean_initializer,
        trainable=False)
    self.moving_variance = self.add_weight(
        shape=shape,
        name='moving_variance',
        initializer=self.moving_variance_initializer,
        trainable=False)
    self.built = True
```

where each variable is of shape `(dim,)`, which is 32 in your case. Since there are four variables, the total number of parameters are `32x4=128`. However, the later two, i.e. `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` are not trainable.

For the use of `Dropout` layer, I don't think you need to worry about it before you have a baseline model. After you have a baseline model, you can improve it by adding extra dropout layers. Of course, the dropout rate should be dependent on your task, and you may have to try different rates to see which one works best.